# open iphone Mail from Actionsheet

Tags: iphone

I want to open Mail app from my app when the one button in actionsheet is pressed, I know this way :

```
 -(IBAtion)openClick:(id)sender
{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:foo@example.com"]];
}
```

but can I write this method inside *if statement* or *switch case*?(in ControlView class NOT NSObject class , because I use actionsheet for this propose)

like this:

```
     - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)modalView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{


switch (buttonIndex)
{
    case 0:
    {

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@”mailto:foo@example.com”]];
        break;
    }
```

I can't test my code because simulator doesn't have the Mail app..
So I need to know is this will work in controlView or must write it in NSObject class ?

+
seconde question :
I want to open Mail app from my app and copy the content in the view to mail body,then the user choice the contact from his contacts list ! Is this way achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)? Then the user won't need to quit your app to send a mail, and you can set the body content more easily, and you can test it on simulator.

---

Your code will work (after fixing the smart quotes).

To set the content of the mail body, use `mailto:abc@example.com?body=The%20Body`. See http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html for the syntax of `mailto:`.

Comment: thank you very much !
nice way! I will try to using MFMailComposeViewController ..but can I use the syntax of mailto without using MFMailComposeViewController class ,In case I don't care to save my app open? because all I need is copying the content !

thank you again ..